# Color Calibration on Sharp LC-32LB370U monitor

Tags: color, color-correction, display-calibration, rgb

I'm having trouble trying to fix the color for my Sharp LED monitor. This has been an issue for about a year or so, and I'd still like to use it, but the wrong colors are too distracting.

I've gone through multiple color correction apps online and all of them seem to get stumped at the bit where it asks for the the RGB to be all corrected.

Fiddled with the display settings on the monitor itself and it wont budge.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What instrument are you using to measure the output of the monitor?

Comment: What do you mean by "won't budge"?

Answer (score 1):

You may have better luck if you **limit your calibration efforts to the center of the screen.**

**The display "gamma"** (for lack of a better term) **of [LCDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lcd) varies with angle of view.** Colors along the edge of the screen appear different from the "same" colors in the center of the screen. Although newer monitors with wider viewing angles exhibit the effect to a lesser extent, it is still present. The uneven color is caused by the monitor's use of polarized light.

The larger the monitor, the greater the variance because of the increased angle between your eyes and the corners of the screen. If you **sit farther away from the screen**, that angle will be reduced, and the color differences should be less distracting.

**Notes:**

- The device in question is a TV. I suspect TVs have lower resolution and color standards than computer monitors because they are meant to be viewed from a much farther distance.
- [LED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED-backlit_LCD) refers to the source of the back light. It still uses the same basic LCD technology.

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution is get a monitor calibration tool like [Colormunki](http://colormunki.com/) or a [ColorVision Monitor Spyder](https://www.dpreview.com/reviews/colorvisionmonitorspyder).